# What is the WPF equivalent of Winforms Drawing.rectangle.union?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rectangles

The title explains it all. I need to know what is the equivalent code in WPF to `drawing.rectange.union()`. I know I could just import `System.Drawing`, but I don't want to do it this way. I am very beginner to WPF.

**EDIT:**

What I am trying to achieve is have two rectangles and make a rectangle that can fit over both of them, for scaling purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [System.Windows.Rect Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.aspx) and its [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms600240.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is none, because WPF doesn't have an equivalent of the `System.Drawing.Rectangle`. WPF does have a `Rectangle`, but because it has only size, and no location, a union is impossible.

If you would describe what you are trying to achieve, you could get a much better answer.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about your situation. All it really says is 'I am trying to union two rectangles'. You'll need to edit it more, and explain your layout. Remember, since rectangles don't have a position, you need to explicitly tell them where to go. You'll also need to tell us the same thing. A code sample would be helpful.